# Would it be possible to train Keras models in parallel inside a loop?

Tags: python, multithreading, keras, multiprocessing, tf.keras

The flow of my problem is somewhat like this. I want to train two separate models in parallel(not necessary in parallel: but parallel training would significantly speed up my loops on the actual problem) on regular intervals(aka loops here for simplicity) on new batches of incoming data.

A simplified flow of the problem is shown below. I wanted to know if the individual training of the Keras models(1 and 2) can be executed in parallel as they don't depend on each other.

```py
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, LSTM

"""ignore following 3 imports as they just illustrate in case someone wants to know
why I need to train in loops 
"""
# from stable_baselines.common.vec_env import SubprocVecEnv
# from stable_baselines.common import set_global_seeds, make_vec_env
# from mycustomfile import SomeImportedEnv, myRL_Agent


# representative data source coming in batches after regular 
# intervals of time for training model 1
def new_data_source_1():

    # generate test and train data for model 1
    X_train_model1 = np.random.rand(100,1,3)
    y_train_model1 = np.random.rand(100,1,2)
    X_test_model1 = np.random.rand(100,1,3)
    y_test_model1 = np.random.rand(100,1,2)

    return [X_train_model1, y_train_model1, X_test_model1,y_test_model1]


# representative data source coming in batches after regular 
# intervals of time for training model 2
def new_data_source_2():

    # generate test and train data for model 2
    X_train_model2 = np.random.rand(60,1,5)
    y_train_model2 = np.random.rand(60,1,2)
    X_test_model2 = np.random.rand(60,1,5)
    y_test_model2 = np.random.rand(60,1,2)

    return [X_train_model2, y_train_model2, X_test_model2, y_test_model2]


def create_keras_model(input_dim, outputdim, input_seq_length, output_seq_length):

    assert input_seq_length==output_seq_length, "This model can take input
       and output sequence of equal length only"

    input_layer = Input(batch_shape=(None, input_seq_length, input_dim))
    hidden_layer = LSTM(16, return_sequences = True)(input_layer)
    output_layer = Dense(outputdim, activation='relu')(hidden_layer)

    model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)

    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')

    return model


"""What I am doing currently to train inside a loop, 2 Keras models, sequentially.
I want to make the model trainings parallel to save time."""
def main():

    model1_created = False
    model2_created = False

    """consider I have to train 10 incoming batches of data from source 1 and 2
    and I have to keep updating my 2 models regularly for subsequent use in a OpenAI Gym 
    environment"""
    for i in range(10):

        # get data from source 1
        X_train_model1, y_train_model1, X_test_model1,y_test_model1 = new_data_source_1()

        # create model for source 1
        if not model1_created:
            model1 = create_keras_model(X_train_model1.shape[-1], y_train_model1.shape[-1][-1],
                                    X_train_model1.shape[-2], y_train_model1.shape[-1][-2])
            model1_created = True

        # train the model1
        _ = model1.fit(X_train_model1, y_train_model1, epochs=100,  initial_epoch=0, 
                             batch_size=32, validation_data=(X_test_model1, y_test_model1))

        # save model1 weights for future use; reason: model1 is needed for 
        # subsequent use in another multiprocessing environment(see StableBaselines 
        # SubprocVecEnv) inside this main function but using the model1 directly 
        # leads to error
        model1.save('Latest_Model_1.hdf5')


        # get data from source 2
        X_train_model2, y_train_model2, X_test_model2,y_test_model2 = new_data_source_2()

        # create model for source 2
        if not model2_created:
            model2 = create_keras_model(X_train_model2.shape[-1], y_train_model2.shape[-1][-1],
                                    X_train_model2.shape[-2], y_train_model2.shape[-1][-2])
            model2_created = True

        # train the model2
        _ = model2.fit(X_train_model1, y_train_model1, epochs=100, initial_epoch=0, 
                             batch_size=32, validation_data=(X_test_model2, y_test_model2))

        # save model2 weights for future use; reason: model2 is needed for 
        # subsequent use in another multiprocessing environment(see StableBaselines 
        # SubprocVecEnv) inside this main function but using the model2 directly 
        # leads to error
        model2.save('Latest_Model_2.hdf5')

        """The following section is an informal representation of why I need
        the models 1 and 2; it is not related to solving my question. You can simply ignore 
        this from the main function in case you want to.
        I have seen people sometimes ask the rationale behind doing training in loops. This 
        entire main() function (with more augmentations above and below) will be running in 
        actual deployment without terminating.
        """
        # mycustomGymenv = SomeImportedEnv(model1path = 'Latest_Model_1.hdf5',
        #                                  model1path = 'Latest_Model_2.hdf5')
        # state = initial_state = mycustomGymenv.initial_state()
        # agent = myRL_Agent(mycustomGymenv)
        # for _ in range(100): # simulate for 100 time steps 
              # action = agent(state) # agent takes action
              # state, reward, over, etc = mycustomGymenv.simulate()  # env returns feedback
              # state, action - save to csv file etc,

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    print("Done!")
```

Any suggestions/edits on improving the clarity of the problem is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on fitting the data chunks sequentially instead of in parallel manner , something like this would work:

```
for _ in range(10):
#somehow cut the data into slices and fit them one by one
    model.fit(data_slice, label_slice ......)
```

As successive calls to **fit** will train the model incrementally .